# curl puts redirected url into adressline of browser

Tags: php, curl

I am pretty new to cURL and have only been using it for a short time.
My problem is that I want to get the content of a page (`file_get_content()` doesn't work) by using cURL. Unfortunately, the site in question has bot protection, meaning it checks whether you are a bot or not when you first arrive at the site. If you are not a bot it will redirect you to the real site with an absolute path (I guess).
Whenever I load this site with cURL it appends the path to my server address.

For example:
My server has the address: `http://examplepage.com/` cURL appends the redirected path to my URL. So it would be something like: `http://examplepage.com/absolute/path?with=parameters`

On the original page, where I try to get the content from, it works because they have a path like that but I do not (I want some html-content of theire site).

Here is my code so far:

```
    <?php

  /* getting site */
  $website = "https://originalsite.com/?some=parameters";
  $redirectURL;

  function curl_download($url) {
    //initialize curl handler
    $c = curl_init();

    // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

    //set url to download
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    // follow redirection
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    //set referer
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://originalsite.com/");

    // User agent
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");

    // Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // Timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    // Download the given URL, and return output
    $output = curl_exec($c);

    // Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
    curl_close($c);

    return $output;
  }

  $content = curl_download($website);

  echo $content;

?>
```

so it'll enter the site where it checks whether I am a bot or not and after that it redirects me to the site (or it least, it tries to).

I have searched the internet and StackOverflow but I couldn't find an answer to my problem.

Comment: what happens when you `print_r()` your `$output` ?

Comment: Nothing different.

Comment: well, you're bound to have either an error encapsulated or some response from the `$output`. Could you add what the value of `$output` is? Whole idea is to debug the request.

Comment: I changed the function like that (sorry, if I did it wrong, still learning):
instead of **return $output** at the end of the function I added **print_r($output)**

Comment: Well, just before you `return $output;` just `print_r($output);` and it should give you debug information of what `$ouput` contains. So we can see whats happening

Comment: Oh no, I see your issue. It is a function. Are you executing it anywhere? Ie, you should have (outside its closure), `$response = curl_download($website);` (since it is being returned from the function)

Comment: I managed to get something. Because there is something just several milliseconds before the other sites checks for bots (the site's loading). In view-source I find this: **HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2017 14:47:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d5e6859019742d48466518f3bedcada2f1486997238; expires=Tue, 13-Feb-18 14:47:18 GMT; path=/; domain=.opskins.com; HttpOnly
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: no-cache
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 33091324fed9639d-FRA**

Comment: Yep, the function is executed right beneath it "$content = curl_download($website)". And after that, I use "echo $content".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that there is some JavaScript code issuing a redirect once you render the page. Try disabling JavaScript in your browser for a quick test.

Comment: I guess that's it. After disabling JS it's only shows, that it is checking if I am a bot. It does not redirect anymore or something.

Comment: Is there a way to get through this anyway?